# How to compare values in a row to a column in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables `Customer_Foods` and `Food_Options`. `Customer_Foods` contains blank values in some of the columns. I am trying to find which values in a given row of `Customer_Foods` are missing from the list of values in `Food_Options`. Eventually, I want to fill in the blanks of the `Customer_Foods` table with options from the second table without duplicating options per ID.

`Customer_Foods`:

| ID | Food1 | Food2 | Food3 | Food4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Apple | BLANK | Pear | Cherry |
| 112 | Apple | Banana | Orange | BLANK |
| 113 | Orange | Cherry | BLANK | Blank |

`Food_Options`:

| Foods |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Cherry |
| Banana |
| Orange |
| Pear |

I have been attempting to use this NOT IN query, but am stumped on how to gather a comparable list of values across a row from the `Customer_Foods` table to compare with a single column of the `Food_Options` table

```
SELECT *
FROM Food_Options
WHERE Foods NOT IN (SELECT *
                    FROM Customer_Foods
                    WHERE ID = 113)
```

It works if I list a single column name (ie Food1) sub-query, but I can't work out how to do this across all of the `Customer_Foods` columns as once.

```
SELECT *
FROM Food_Options
WHERE Foods NOT IN (SELECT Food1
                    FROM Customer_Foods
                    WHERE ID = 113)
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you want an answer for.

Comment: Does "BLANK" mean NULL? Or an empty string `''`? Or one blank `' '`? Or can it be any number of blanks (e.g. `'    '`)?

Comment: It would be good did you add a table with the desired result. Do I understand this correctly that you want to create all possible rows that you get by replacing the blanks with fruits not yet in the row? So for ID 111 you'd get two rows, one with 'Banana' and one with 'Orange' for food2? For ID 112 you'd get two rows, one with 'Cherry' and one with 'Pear' for food4? And for ID 113 you'd get 6 rows with (food3, food4) = Apple/Banana, Banana/Apple, Apple/Pear, Pear/Apple, Banana/Pear, Pear/Banana?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I left the tag as 'sql' as I was not given a specific DBMS. I've been working on the problem within sql lite if that helps. Also, the blanks are 0 length strings.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The end result I am working towards is a still a single row per ID. For ID 111, I want to fill the blank with either banana or orange (ie any of the unused items in the Food_Options table)

Comment: Maybe it would be much easier and more scalable if you could modify your Customer_Foods table design to have only three columns (ID,  Food_Type, Food_Value), where you could use conditional aggregation to get the current table design, anyway, check the updated posted answer I hope it helps you.

Comment: Do you want to update the table Customer_Foods, or just a SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2):

You need to select all food columns in the sub-query, using a `union all` and CTE, you may modify your query as the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT ID, Food1 AS Food FROM Customer_Foods
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Food2 FROM Customer_Foods
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Food3 FROM Customer_Foods
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ID, Food4 FROM Customer_Foods
 )

SELECT *
FROM Food_Options
WHERE Foods NOT IN
    (SELECT Food
     FROM CTE
     WHERE ID = 113)
```

And if your DBMS supports the unpivot functionality (like SQL Server), you could use it instead of the union.

To get a single row with blank food columns replaced by the missing food values from the `Food_Options` table, try the following:

```
WITH CTE AS( -- unpivot keeping the order of each column
  SELECT ID, Food1 AS Foods, 1 AS ord FROM Customer_Foods
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Food2, 2 FROM Customer_Foods
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Food3, 3 FROM Customer_Foods
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ID, Food4, 4 FROM Customer_Foods
),
CTE2 AS ( -- get the missing foods and give them numbering 
  SELECT FO.Foods,C1.ord,C1.ID,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FO.Foods) RN
  FROM Food_Options FO LEFT JOIN CTE C1 ON FO.Foods=C1.Foods  AND C1.ID= 113
  WHERE C1.ID IS NULL
),
CTE3 AS( -- match the missing foods based on the order of columns (ord) and missing foods order
  SELECT C1.ID, C1.ord, COALESCE(NULLIF(C1.Foods,''),C2.Foods) Foods
  FROM 
   (
    SELECT ID, ord,Foods, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Foods='' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, ord) RN 
    FROM CTE WHERE ID = 113
   ) C1  LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2  
  ON C2.RN = C1.RN
)
SELECT ID, -- use conditional aggregation to re-pivot the data
  MAX(CASE WHEN ord=1 THEN Foods END) Food1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ord=2 THEN Foods END) Food2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ord=3 THEN Foods END) Food3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ord=4 THEN Foods END) Food4
FROM CTE3
GROUP BY ID
```

The output for ID=113:

```
ID  Food1   Food2   Food3   Food4
113 Orange  Cherry  Apple   Banana
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eLOpfHam)